# How do I remove the line on the ICS spinner?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-spinner

I am trying to remove the line on the ICS spinner. Currently it look as follows:
[image]
I would like to remove the line below the text"investment strategy in this case" so that just the triangle on the bottom right remains.Is there a way to do this? Here's my sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.justin.abc"
    android:id="@+id/top_bar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
   <!--   android:background="@color/background_action_bar" -->


    <com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_background_holo_light"
        android:minWidth="200dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/context_menu_button"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="48.5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingRight="14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/testdrawable" />

</merge>
```

I have used the default icsspinner code online (open source), any way I can modify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 9-patch image named `spinner_default_holo_light_am.9.png` which is the one that has the thin line at the bottom.

You can create your own custom spinner that inherits from `com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner` and change that 9-patch to one with the design you want, in this case, removing the thin line.

The 9-patch can be seen here: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-xxhdpi/spinner_default_holo_light_am.9.png

(This assuming you are using a "light" theme)

Comment: everytime I manually remove the line in the image, it stretches the triangular image, is there a way I can do it programmatically so that the 9 patch image doesnt stretch ?

Comment: You have to create a new 9-patch with a "transparent line" instead of the current line, so that "transparent line" is the the one that stretches.

Comment: without that hack do you know what is causing the front bottom line to stretch programmatically?

Comment: It is not a hack. That is what 9-patches are for, they define which parts of the image can strech and which cannot. Take a look at http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html